# Default cube has 6 zero faces in 3D printer tool

Tags: edges, faces

I've seen this question on the web, videos, forums, etc. with no solution in sight.

This problem exists in 3.6.1 LTS. Naturally it causes problems with CURA, "non-manifold object".

Is there a solution for this? I've tried ALL the "solutions" I found online, with no resolution.
The problem exists on the default cube and any other cube I instantiate or modification of the default cube.

Thanks for bearing with me, repeating this question, but hey! Where's the solution?

To clarify a bit, the bare default will show properly in CURA and in MS 3D viewer. But my completed mesh with other objects in boolean difference with the main cube do not come out properly in both of those apps.

I would like to share my file, but I'm not sure how. I'm relatively new to Blender 3D, just been a month using it, but I sure learned a lot from videos, docs and the web, thanks to all for that! But his problem is a poser for me.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! I'm not sure what you mean, because the default cube is manifold and should be 3d printable. If that was not so in your case then it's a bug and off-topic? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I just tried it on 3.6.1 with the bundled 3D-Print Toolbox. The only complaint it gives me, is 1 overhang face. When clicking, it selects the bottom face, which, strictly speaking, is an overhang, considering it has no support. However, since it would be supported by the printer itself, it's not a problem. Why you get complaints about zero faces, I can't say, but my guess is that there's something wrong with either you installation or you configuration.

Comment: It depends on the file format you use to export your model to cura. Some formats automatically unweld edges so your model will be non-manifold. The defacto format is stl which should preserve manifold-ness (if that word exists ?)

Comment: Also zero-faces can be very very small faces, as the software has a threshold under which it will consider faces to have zero area. Consider scaling your object way up when exporting it, there might be a dimension mismatch

Comment: Titanius Anglesmith, in what way would my configuration be at fault? It was a clean installation of 3.6.1 STL on a W110 PC. Which part of Blender 3D config would cause or fix this issue?

Comment: Gorgious, I did use STL file format. As noted in my original post, I VERY thoroughly looked for solutions, tried them all. No cures. The problem exists from first cube to finished object, which has other stuff in it.

Comment: Harry McKenzie, Hi! How do I share files, screenshots? I can accurately describe it. Open Blender, there's the cube. Open 3D print tools, check all. There's the "zero faces 6". click that in Edit Mode, all 6 sides of the cube are highlighted. What in my config would cause that? One thing, I can make that go away in 3D print tools by setting the "Degenerate" parameter to 0.000001 ... but that doesn't cure the CURA issues.